# Not able to send JSON Array with jersey Response, "getting error Generating incomplete JSON "

Tags: json, jersey

I am trying to send JSONArray with Jersey response. Here is the sample code
This looks easy but I am getting the bellow error

> org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller marshall
>   SEVERE: Generating incomplete JSON

```js
    @GET
 @Path("/test")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 public Response test(){
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
  array.put("123");
  array.put("456");
  array.put("789");
  return Response.ok(array).build();
 }
```

I tried this also, but no luck

```html
        @GET
     @Path("/test")
     @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     public Response test(){
      JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
      array.put("123");
      array.put("456");
      array.put("789");
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
      obj.put("Array", array);
      return Response.ok(obj).build();
     }
```

Dependencies are fine, because I am able to run other service,
I did google for this error but could not find proper solution for this.

**What causes this error`org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller marshall SEVERE: Generating incomplete JSON` to occur?**

**How do we handle it?**

**Update 1 :**
When I send the array as String it did work

> return Response.ok(array.toString()).build();

I am surprise, is jersey not able to recognize JSONOnject or JSONArray?

Comment: _"is jersey not able to recognize JSONObject or JSONArray"_ - No. Not without extra libraries to help. I suggest avoiding the json.org library all together and get used to using POJOs to model your data and use the Jackson library (and matching JAX-RS JSON provider) to handle the (de)serialization. Nobody really uses the json.org library for RSET application. it is a very beginner library with a very tedious to use API. Most developers use POJOs to map to the JSON and have the JSON deserialized to POJO and vice versa.

Comment: Have a look at the [Jersey docs for JSON support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json). Don't bother with the MOXy or JSON-P sections. Use Jackson instead.